# Overwriting an implementation of function pointer and use for shared library

Tags: c, pointers, dll

This is a unique situation in `C`.

Say we a library called `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` and in both we the same function name, `Get_A`, assume `Get_A` is called by the system.

Say `libbar` is loaded and then its `Get_A` is called with parameter `G`. `G` is a struct with some function pointers, with one of interest:

`(*G)->RegisterBaz`

So in `libbar`'s invocation of `Get_A`, we want to mutate the pointer to that RegisterBaz function and then call `libfoo`'s version of `Get_A` by means of dlopen + dlsym.

One thing I tried was directly assigning but then I got a compiler error of that READ ONLY variables are unassignable, so I tried going through pointers:

```
// not void * but actually some function signature typedefed.
void *f_ptr = (*G)->RegisterBaz;
*&f_ptr = r_n;
```

Where `r_n` is a plain C function with the same signature as `RegisterBaz`

and in `r_n` I call the original implementation of `RegisterBaz`

So while this doesn't seg fault, it doesn't end up calling my wrapped function either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you did the direct assignment, you were probably trying to assign a function to a const function pointer; this obviously is not something you can do.

Also, in the code:

```
void *f_ptr = (*G)->RegisterBaz;
*&f_ptr = r_n;
```

in actuality, `f_ptr` is pointing to the same thing `(*G)->RegisterBaz` is pointing at, so when you change `f_ptr` with `*&` (basically a no-op) you aren't modifying `(*G)->RegisterBaz` at all.

In addition, you can't assign function pointers to object pointers; something of `void *` type is only guaranteed to be able to hold object pointers. *(INCITS-ISO-IEC 9899-2011 [6.3.2.3p7](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7))*

So if for whatever reason you are dead set on changing `(*G)->RegisterBaz` directly you can do something like:

```
void (**f_ptr)(void) = (void (**)(void))&((*G)->RegisterBaz);
*f_ptr = r_n;
```

BUT since you are going to be calling through `(*G)->RegisterBaz` you need to make sure the replacement function signature matches the function signature of what `(*G)->RegisterBaz` happens to be pointing at.

You will also get a warning unless `f_ptr` is of type **pointer to pointer to `"insert signature of called function here"`**.

I need to reiterate this is NOT something you usually want to be doing, and so I can make no guarantees this will work. But if you are dead set on it this is how you would do it (basically you are aliasing the const function pointer to a non-const one.)

Comment: Hmm, doing this is giving me a seg fault.

Comment: Are you 100% certain the function you are replacing provides all the same functionalities? You can't just replace a library  function with your own, and just because the signature matches expect it to be dandy.

Comment: The signature is correct, what could be wrong, where can I start to find clues or look. AFAIK Things are correct on my end.

Comment: Ah apologies, I had forgotten a &, so try with my edited code.

Comment: Unfortunately still a seg fault, I am doing this on Android so also looking for way to look up lldb to app on command line.

Comment: Does assigning it directly work? If `(*G)->RegisterBaz = function` doesn't work, then this way won't either.

Comment: Doing that kind of direct assignment gives compiler error of 'read-only variable cannot be assigned'

Comment: Seems I misunderstood what you had tried; if that is the case then `RegisterBaz` is a const function pointer and cannot be changed.

Comment: Isn't there a way to cast it away? Or force it like this indirect way?

Comment: You COULD try casting it if you really want to force this, though I can't guarantee what will happen with that. It may work or it may completely break everything.

Comment: But where would I put the cast, can you edit with that as 'experimental' answer =P

Comment: Its crashing because of 'SIGSEGV, address access protected'